# How to save the checked boxes?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, jquery, metabox

What i am trying to achieve is this

I have created a ***custom post(offer)***, i have another ***custom post created (listing)***.

I want to add a metabox in listing, which will recieve check list of all offers

[image]

i have achieved this as shown in **image** using code below.

```
function op_register_menu_meta_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'op-menu-meta-box-id',
    esc_html__( 'Custom offers Checklist (select any 2)', 'text-domain' ),
    'op_render_menu_meta_box',
    'listing'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_listing', 'op_register_menu_meta_box' );
function op_render_menu_meta_box() {
// Metabox content
$getPostsToSelect = get_posts('post_type=offers&numberposts=-1');
foreach ($getPostsToSelect as $aPostsToSelect) {
?>
<label>
    <input 
      type='checkbox' 
      name='yourcustom_meta[]' 
      class='postsToSelect'
      value='<?php echo $aPostsToSelect->ID ?>'
     /> 
    <?php echo $aPostsToSelect->post_title;
    ?>
</label><br />
<?php
}}
```

Now what what i want to get is out of the several checklist of offers, we can select two offers by checking them.

**Q1. How to save the checked boxes?**

**Q2. How to use them *(the checked only) later to display on single.php?**

And then when we publish the listing, the checked offers will be printed on **archive-offers.php**

I need to achieve this, please help me!

Comment: jQuery is javascript, `functions.php` is PHP, there's further research you need to do, e.g. what are metaboxes, how do you add a metabox, how do you load javascript in WP, how do you load it in the admin area, and how to do you use javascript with a metabox

Comment: i have updated my requirement! @TomJNowell Pleae help me achieve the feature

Comment: hmmm now that you've updated your question, I don't see what jQuery or javascript have to do with it, it can all be done with PHP. I take it the problem you're grappling with is that you can display the checkboxes but you don't know how to save the value?

Comment: Yes, right. I need help with php. Please help me achieve it. @TomJNowell

Comment: Simplify your question so that you know how to save the checkboxes. Once you've done that, work on making sure only 2 can be selected. Step by step. This way you're much more likely to get answers, and they'll be far more useful. Edit your question so it just has your code, and ask how to save the result. Then you can create a new question asking how to display it. And another on how to limit check boxes to 2, etc

Comment: I updated my question @TomJNowell please guide me with code to achieve it.

Comment: Save:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: You can use the WordPress checked function for rendering as checked:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP in your functions.php file to insert inline JavaScript (including jQuery) using WordPress hooks.

In your example, you could use the `admin_print_scripts-post.php` action hook to print your inline jQuery like so:

```
function wpse_admin_print_scripts_edit() {
  echo "<script>var limit = 2;' .
    'jQuery('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {' .
      'if(jQuery('input.single-checkbox:checked').length > limit) {' .
        'this.checked = false;' .
      '}' .
    '});</script>";
}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'wpse_admin_print_scripts_edit' );
```

Comment: I have updated my question, Please help me achieve the feature.
Thank you!