# A good strategy to print custom posts (offer) that are checked inside the metabox of a post?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, metabox

**the code for getting the metabox in image is:**

```
function op_register_menu_meta_box() {
add_meta_box(
'op-menu-meta-box-id',
esc_html__( 'Custom offers Checklist (select any 2)', 'text-domain' ),
'op_render_menu_meta_box',
'listing'
);
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_listing', 'op_register_menu_meta_box' );
function op_render_menu_meta_box() {
// Metabox content
$getPostsToSelect = get_posts('post_type=offers&numberposts=-1');
foreach ($getPostsToSelect as $aPostsToSelect) {
?>
<label>
<input 
  type='checkbox' 
  name='yourcustom_meta[]' 
  class='postsToSelect'
  value='<?php echo $aPostsToSelect->ID ?>'
 /> 
<?php echo $aPostsToSelect->post_title;
?>
</label><br />
<?php
}}
```

Currently i have got to this on edit post page!

[image]

**the code of archive-offers.php is:** and i want to print it on archive page

```
<?php
/**
* The main template file***/
get_header(); ?>
<?php
        /**
        * The main template file
        * It puts together the home page if no home.php file exists.
        *
        * @package Simple Blog Theme
        */
        get_header(); ?>
            <div class="row mb-5">
                <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                        <span itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://google.com/article" /></span>
                        <div class="my-5">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Blog Post -->
```

> **I want to print 1st offer here!**
>       **I want to print 2nd offer here!**

```
                        <?php
                    // Note: this loop is a simplified version of a loop published in a post at Elegant Themes
                    // Source: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites
                    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
                            <div>
                                <h1 class="card-title mb-4" itemprop="headline">
                                    <span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Rookie Bloggers">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://sample1.nepromedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/logo.jpg">
        <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://sample1.nepromedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/logo.jpg"></span>


                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </h1>
                                <div class=" ml-1 mr-1 row alert alert-info text-info mb-5">
                                    <span class="col-sm"><i class="fas fa-edit "></i> Last Modified On</span> <span class="col-sm" itemprop="datePublished">
                                <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="<?php the_modified_date(); ?>"><strong><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt "></i>
                        <?php the_time( 'F j, Y' ); ?></strong></span>
                                    <span class="col-sm" itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                            <meta itemprop="name" content="<?php the_author(); ?>">
        <meta itemprop="publisher"><?php $args = array('class' => 'nimesh12' , ); ?> <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 25, $default, $alt, $args); ?>
        <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
                                </div>

                                <span itemprop='image' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject'><meta itemprop="url"content="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?></span>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="card-text mb-5" itemprop="description">
                                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <?php
                        $prev_post = get_previous_post();
                        if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
                                        <strong><a href="<?php echo $prev_post->guid ?>"><?php echo 'Older posts' ?></a></strong>
                                        <?php endif ?>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>

                            <?php else : ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

***Mechanism***:
when i check two of them and publish them, they should remain checked here!
After that those selected Custom posts (offer) should be printed on **archive-offer.php**

what should i do to achieve this?
Help Appreciated!

Comment: Share the code that outputs the "Custom Offer Section" meta box. Secondly, elaborate "*printed on archive-offer.php*"; i.e., share the code of the *archive-offer.php* file, and mark where should the selected "offers" should be added to. (And a sample markup/HTML of the "offer" like `<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3><p><?php the_content(); ?></p>`)

Comment: Look lookup. add_meta_box() and get_post_meta()

Comment: Thank you! here is my link to the question, its explained in detail. @SallyCJ  i have added get header and footer in archive-offers.php
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298610/how-to-save-the-checked-boxes

Comment: @SallyCJ I have updated the current questtion with details you wanted!
Can you please help me?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/299146/137402).

Comment: It is solved i followed your link! @SallyCJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is achieved in this way!

```
function op_register_menu_meta_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'op-menu-meta-box-id', // Metabox ID
     esc_html__( 'Custom offers Checklist (select any 2)', 'text-domain' ), //Metabox Title
    'op_render_menu_meta_box', // Metabox Callback Function
    'listing' // Place Where this Metbax Should Appear
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_listing', 'op_register_menu_meta_box' ); //Metabox Hook
```

**The callback function!**

```
function op_render_menu_meta_box( $post ) { // Metabox Callback Function Called
// Get the selected 'offers' (array of post IDs).
$offers_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_offers_ids', true );

// Displays a nonce field, without referrer field.
wp_nonce_field( 'save-offers-meta', 'offers_meta_nonce', false );

// Metabox content
$getPostsToSelect = get_posts(
                    array(
                        'post_type' => 'offers',
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    ));
foreach ($getPostsToSelect as $aPostsToSelect) {
?>
<label>
    <input 
      type='checkbox' 
      name='offers_meta[]' 
      class='postsToSelect'
      value='<?php echo $aPostsToSelect->ID ?>'
      <?php checked( true, in_array( $aPostsToSelect->ID, $offers_ids ) ); ?>
     /> 
    <?php echo $aPostsToSelect->post_title;
?>
</label><br/>
<?php
}}
```

**Save Metabox function!**

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'op_save_offers_meta', 10, 2 );
function op_save_offers_meta( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Make sure that we can save the meta data.
    if ( ( empty( $post_id ) || empty( $post ) || ( 'listing' !== get_post_type( $post ) ) )
    || ( empty( $_POST['post_ID'] ) || $_POST['post_ID'] != $post_id || ! isset( $_POST['offers_meta'] ) )
    || ( empty( $_POST['offers_meta_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['offers_meta_nonce'], 'save-offers-meta' ) )
    || ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $offers_ids = wp_parse_id_list( $_POST['offers_meta'] );
    if ( ! empty( $offers_ids ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_offers_ids', $offers_ids );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_offers_ids' );
    }
}
```

**At last the procedure to echo checked !**

```
<?php $post_id = get_the_ID();

// Get the selected 'offers' (array of post IDs).
$offers_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $post_id, '_offers_ids', true );

$q = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'offers',
    'post__in'  => $offers_ids,
] );

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
    ?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php
    }
}

wp_reset_query ?>
```

**Big thanks to @sallycj**