# Save or update data when custom post published

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, database, metabox

I have metabox on my custom post screen.

[image]

***How to save them when any of them are checked and then use or echo those checked offers to display on single.php?***

my code for metabox is

```
function op_register_menu_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'op-menu-meta-box-id', // Metabox ID
         esc_html__( 'Custom offers Checklist (select any 2)', 'text-domain' ), //Metabox Title
        'op_render_menu_meta_box', // Metabox Callback Function
        'listing' // Place Where this Metbax Should Appear
        );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_listing', 'op_register_menu_meta_box' ); //Metabox Hook

function op_render_menu_meta_box() { // Metabox Callback Function Called
    // Metabox content
    $getPostsToSelect = get_posts(
                        array(
                            'post_type' => 'offers',
                            'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        ));
    foreach ($getPostsToSelect as $aPostsToSelect) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'prfx_nonce' ); //Adds a valid nonce for security (1. Filename should be unique, 2. Object name should be diffrent for forms)
    ?>
    <label>
        <input 
          type='checkbox' 
          name='offers_meta' 
          class='postsToSelect'
          value='<?php echo $aPostsToSelect->ID ?>'
         /> 
        <?php echo $aPostsToSelect->post_title;

?>
    </label><br/>
    <?php
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***How to save them when any of them are checked***

You can use [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/), like so:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'op_save_offers_meta', 10, 2 );
function op_save_offers_meta( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Make sure that we can save the meta data.
    if ( ( empty( $post_id ) || empty( $post ) || ( 'listing' !== get_post_type( $post ) ) )
    || ( empty( $_POST['post_ID'] ) || $_POST['post_ID'] != $post_id || ! isset( $_POST['offers_meta'] ) )
    || ( empty( $_POST['offers_meta_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['offers_meta_nonce'], 'save-offers-meta' ) )
    || ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $offers_ids = wp_parse_id_list( $_POST['offers_meta'] );
    if ( ! empty( $offers_ids ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_offers_ids', $offers_ids );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_offers_ids' );
    }
}
```

I have also altered your `op_render_menu_meta_box()`:

```
function op_render_menu_meta_box( $post ) { // Metabox Callback Function Called
    // Get the selected 'offers' (array of post IDs).
    $offers_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_offers_ids', true );

    // Displays a nonce field, without referrer field.
    wp_nonce_field( 'save-offers-meta', 'offers_meta_nonce', false );

    // Metabox content
    $getPostsToSelect = get_posts(
                        array(
                            'post_type' => 'offers',
                            'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        ));
    foreach ($getPostsToSelect as $aPostsToSelect) {
    ?>
    <label>
        <input 
          type='checkbox' 
          name='offers_meta[]' 
          class='postsToSelect'
          value='<?php echo $aPostsToSelect->ID ?>'
          <?php checked( true, in_array( $aPostsToSelect->ID, $offers_ids ) ); ?>
         /> 
        <?php echo $aPostsToSelect->post_title;

?>
    </label><br/>
    <?php
}
}
```

> ***and then use or echo those checked offers***

You can use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to retrieve the 'offers' (i.e. `array` of post IDs) — just like in the above `op_render_menu_meta_box()` `function`, and do a standard The Loop to display the post details. Example:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();

// Get the selected 'offers' (array of post IDs).
$offers_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $post_id, '_offers_ids', true );

$q = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'offers',
    'post__in'  => $offers_ids,
] );

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
    ?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php
    }
}

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: You're welcome and all the best!